# What is the effect of the pseudo header in UDP?

Tags: tcp, udp

I know the pseudo header is used to compute the checksum of UDP.But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the checksum has to be in the UDP packet before it's given to the IP layer (which adds its own IP header). The pseudo header contains only a few parts of the information that would be in the IP header, and calculates the checksum out of these parts and the UDP content.

After the checksum is calculated, the pseudo header is discarded, it is not transferred!

The client then receives the full IP packet and can validate the checksum with the UDP packet contents and the full IP header.

Comment: Maybe with the pseudo header,we can also validate  the correctness of IP packet and UDP packet?And  without the pseudo header, we can only validate  the correctness of UDP packet?

Comment: Well, in a custom implementation you could calculate your checksum as you wish and only use values from the UDP packet. But if you want to follow the regular UDP protocol, the checksum calculation includes some IP header information (e.g. sender and receiver IP... information that does not exist yet on the UDP layer)